# What was meant when Aro said this line?

Tags: twilight

What did Aro mean when he said, "*Maintaining our secret has never been more imperative*"? It is on the *Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn Part 2* trailer and I'm very curious to know what this line meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't correctly quote. But I think it is the third book there is a line that goes something like:
For the first time in history men have created weapons which can kill vampires.

Which means, for the first time since vampires have existed they have a threat. Since they can't have more numbers than humans(else they run out of food), they must use stealth to live.

Answer (score 2):

"Maintaining our secret has never been more imperative" is a command, something that demands attention or action, a necessity that "our" the vampires must assert and kept from the knowledge of others.  This is at any cost including killing non vampires/vampires that are lacking caution.